# image not loading in opencv2

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am using opencv2 in python to load image using the numpy

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img=cv2.imgread('C:\im.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

when I execute this code the image window pops up but it doesn't show any image and crashes up.

Comment: That is not "uploading" an image. Please use correct terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lack the `waitKey()` function after `imshow`.

Comment: after imshow ;)